# iOS 8 : App crashes while trying to remove single event from device calendar

Tags: objective-c, ios8, ekevent, ekeventstore

I Have used EKSpanThisEvent so when I try to remove single event from device calendar it crashes, Instead of that if I use EKSpanFutureEvents it does not get crash but it will remove all future events with same eventIdentifier even though we try to remove single event from device calendar

Crash detail is as Follow
Assertion failure in -[EKEvent _deleteThisOccurrence]
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'I screwed up somewhere in date calculation'

I tried all solutions from all sources but unfortunately none was useful, Any Help will be Highly Appreciated

CODE

```
  if([identifier length] > 0)
{
    __block EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];


    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) return;

        NSDate *eventdate = [commonUnit getSystemTimeZoneDateFromDate:strdate fromFormate:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:eventdate
                                                                endDate:[eventdate dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400]
                                                              calendars:nil];
        NSMutableArray *events = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate]];
        NSPredicate *predicateidentifier = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"eventIdentifier = '%@'",identifier]];
        [events filterUsingPredicate:predicateidentifier];
        if (events.count > 0) {
            NSError* error = nil;
            [store removeEvent:events[0] span:status?EKSpanFutureEvents:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
            if(error == nil)
            {
                callbackBlock(TRUE);
            }
            else
            {
                callbackBlock(FALSE);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```